# Atom Editor Snippets

Tags: atom-editor, cson

I have a simple snippet:

```
'.source.js':
  'Console log':
    'prefix': '>log'
    'body': 'console.log($1)'
```

It worked as expected for a while, perhaps I installed a package or something, but now when I hit tab after typing `>log` the right brace doesn't disappear, giving me `>console.log();`.

How would one remedy this situation?

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works here.

Comment: Mind sharing a copy of your snippets.cson?

Comment: I copied your snipped to produce the result.